# SQL Server CTE query producing unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a CTE like this:

```
WITH CTE(PartNum, RowIndex) AS
(
        -- Anchor Member
        SELECT
            PartNum
            ,CAST(OurQty AS INT) AS RowIndex
        FROM dbo.RcvDtl
        WHERE OurQty > 0
        UNION ALL
        -- Recursive Member
        SELECT
            PartNum
            ,RowIndex - 1
        FROM CTE
        WHERE RowIndex - 1 > 0
)
SELECT 
    tbl1.PONum, tbl1.PartNum, 
    CAST(tbl1.OurQty AS INT) AS Quantity, 
    tbl2.RowIndex AS RowIndex
FROM 
    dbo.RcvDtl AS Tbl1
INNER JOIN 
    CTE AS Tbl2 ON Tbl1.PartNum = Tbl2.PartNum
WHERE 
    tbl1.PONum = '63'
ORDER BY 
    Tbl1.PartNum OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Which runs on the following table:

```
| PartNum | Quantity
---------------------
  10050857    6
  10050886    10
  10050923    24
```

The idea of the query is to duplicate a record (PartNum) based on its quantity. The query duplicates the first PartNum '10050857' by 46 records (6+(6+10+24)) when it should just duplicate 6 times, the second PartNum '10050886' by 10 records as expected and the final part num '10050923' by 24 records as expected.

Why is the query duplicating the first record by an accumulation of the records following the first record?

Comment: It looks and works fine - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0b685/2

Comment: Although I have changed some column names to make it run. So you are probably using a wrong column somewhere which makes for a wrong joins and results. Please double check your column names (Quantity<>OurQty?)

Comment: When I run it on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 it returns 80 records

Comment: Also check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570771/split-a-row-on-2-or-more-rows-depending-on-a-column/17570941#17570941 for some other ideas how to achieve same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the names a little, but your CTE does work:

```
WITH CTE(PartNum, RowIndex) AS
(
        -- Anchor Member
        SELECT
            PartNum
            ,CAST(OurQty AS INT) AS RowIndex
        FROM dbo.RcvDtl
        WHERE OurQty > 0
        UNION ALL
        -- Recursive Member
        SELECT
            PartNum
            ,RowIndex - 1
        FROM CTE
        WHERE RowIndex - 1 > 0
)
SELECT CTE.PartNum, dbo.RcvDtl.OurQty, CTE.RowIndex from CTE INNER JOIN dbo.RcvDtl
ON CTE.PartNum = dbo.RcvDtl.PartNum
order by PartNum,RowIndex
```

Just check your code again, it will work. Nice trick too, I love a bit of CTE!